# Adding a portlet from one liferay container to another liferay portal

Tags: liferay, portlet

I have two liferay portals. I have deployed few portlets on Portal A. I want to use them on Portal B.

What is the appropriate way to do this?

Comment: Just deploy portlets to both portal servers.

Comment: No I don't want to keep them in both server. I was to host it at one place and use it in another.

Comment: Use Web Service Remote Portlets.

Comment: Maybe you could use an iframe portlet with the URL of the portlet on the other server.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use them in each other.

REASON : You liferay portal is your web-application server, your portlets are the web apps of that server, you have deployed them on specific server.

So, you simply cannot use this like the way you are thinking (I think your wild guess would be sharing "webapps" across portal)

The following possible solutions you can use for that

1. Use WSRP (Web Services for Remote Portlets), in this one, your one portal will host portlets and it can be used at remote portlets for another one.
2. Use Liferay Services (service.xml and remote-service=true), in this one, one portal must host liferay services as remote service =true, another portal can consume this and done.
3. Use Liferay Instance and not portals, Use a single Liferay portal server with 2 Liferay instances for 2 different web applications. This is possible, in this one, you can share all the resources on both the instance, and you can host them differently also.

Hope this helps!